# No file is created when I choose 'Save style ...' in layer properties

Tags: qgis, symbology

First of all, I create a layer using the Add Delimited Text Layer plugin. The layer contains longitudinal and latitudinal data and a number that is assigned to each data point. When using a graduated color to style my data points, I define classes based on a specific range. I'd like to use the same classes for all of my layers. Therefore, I want to save my style using the 'Save style ...' button, in order to be able to load it into the other layers. However, when saving the .qml file, no file is created in the specified folder (e.g. desktop).

Another strategy may be to set the current style as default by using 'Save As Default'. When clicking 'Restore Default Style' in the other layers, a prompt shows up that says 'style not found in database'.

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Important piece of information: What software is this?

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan - its Qgis.."add delimiter plugin" he mentioned is from Qgis

Comment: Which QGIS version and operating system are you using? I cannot confirm this bug on any of my machines.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for starting to help me out in the first place! As you may have understood, I'm completely new to GIS. I accidentally resolved the problem myself. Obviously, the qml files are stored in the same folder as where my original data (that I imported using the Add Delimiter Plugin) is stored, even though I specified a folder when saving the qml files. This I find a bit confusing. I'm using Qgis version 1.7.4 and it's running on 32-bit Windows 7. Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm the error on a MacOSX 10.6.8 running qGis 1.7.4.
The error only happens with from text-file imported Layers.

Answer (score 3):

This is still an open bug in QGIS for CSV-layers
http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8285

Answer (score 2):

Copy and pasting the style from 1 layer to another appears to be a workaround for qgis 2.10 Pisa on Windows . Just right click on the layer, choose styles -> copy styles and then select the other destination layer and right click -> paste styles